# I need to make a shape for my web page

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a web page that has shapes and stuff but the only problem with that I cant make a shape everyone knows how in khan academy they have fake programming where we can make shapes like this simple:

```
    rect(100,100,100,100);
```

ps that programming doesn't work and I'm trying to find a way to do that in real programming

also I need a way to set the coordinates to it too with it working on many browsers

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What is 'fake programming', 'khan academy', and what's the link to the photograph for?

Comment: fake programming is programming that is not valid but is on the site

Comment: khan academy is a learning site used by many schools online

Comment: and there is no photograph

Comment: He's new to programming. Give him a break.

Comment: No, he will have to give us a break.  If you want to ask a question here, make sure it is answerable.  Someone might be new to this, but they are not new to asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what you mean. It is basically their own library and methods.

What they're using is HTML5 Canvas. In order to replicate this, you should learn how to use canvas.

For now, use this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//How this works: Use ctx.fillRect(x,y,width,height) instead of rect(x,y,width,height)

ctx.fillRect(10,10,100,100);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

When I started programming, I used Khanacademy. I gave up quickly for codecademy.com, which has awesome courses.

Comment: you guys spend all the time disliking mine whats why I have low reputation and I cant like this pls stop wasting your time and like this and don't dislike mone so I can like urs